# Bottom sheet и recycleview

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheet

Такой вопрос. Есть Bottom Sheet в котором есть header со с фильтрами и внутри заголовка ещё один recycleview. Далее идут элементы. Заголовок не должен обновляться, а остальные элементы обновляются при изменении положения карты. Но так как заголовок является частью Adapter, то он тоже обновляется. Я придумал так, что при обновлении данных, удалять все элементы из adapter кроме заголовка ну и notyfilesetdatachanged обновлять. Соответственно, вопрос. Хороший ли это вариант? И ещё вопрос, когда recycleview находится в заголовке другого recycleview, то он не даёт скролить bottom sheet, как это можно исправить?

Comment: бред, зачем хеадер в recycler тулить?На будущее имейте привычку кидать код в вопросе.

Comment: А как сделать, если нужно чтобы был горизонтальный recycleview и вертикальный.

Comment: Если бы вы прояснили что такое заголовок RecycleView...

Comment: В заголовке лежат фильтры, а именно radiogroup, checkbox и тд. Так же там есть рекомендации в виде горизонтального Recycleview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему через NestedScrollView для того, чтобы не заносить в один recycleview другие. А чтобы recycleview давал скролить

`recycleview.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recycleview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`